I don't know how to mockup PLC client data using node js
I don't know how to mockup PLC client data using node js, in order to test the data exchange of the PLC monitoring system?
My PLC map is currently
{
 "ios": {
 "io": [
 {
 "name": "HEARTBEAT",
 "address": [
 "D0100",
 "2"
 ],
 "type": "INT"
 }
 ]
 }
}

I want to code a PLC client mockup project using node js so that the data transmitted matches the above sample.
I am using nodejs net.socket, it works fine. I want the mockup of the data sent to be similar to the PLC door sample data
